# Google Drive SDK Sample PHP Exception

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Hi i try to set up the Google code sample for the Google Drive Api following those steps:
https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php

But i got an exception when i try the authentication :

> exception 'apiAuthException' with message 'Error fetching OAuth2
>   access token, message: 'redirect_uri_mismatch'

Any idea if i could have miss something in the config process?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you register the app in the APIs Console and have the Redirect URI match the URI of your web server?

Did you set the REDIRECT_URI (together with CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET) in config.php?

https://developers.google.com/drive/examples/php#setting_up_the_client_id_client_secret_and_other_oauth_20_parameters

Comment: Thank you that was the problem in config.php, I missed this field ;)